# Why do setters improve performance in JS/Angular array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working with some performance issues with Angular and I noticed in the code

```
// TODO(perf): generate setters to shave off ~40ms or 1-1.5%
```

How would creating a Javascript getter setter for something like this...

```
$scope.$first = (index === 0);
```

Increase perf and what is a "setter" for that? Something like this?

```
scope.$first = function(){
  index === 0;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `setter` in javascript is something as follow:

```
var dogs = {'medor': ..., 'fido': ...}
var my = {};
Object.defineProperty(my, "dogname", {
  set: function (name) { this.dog = dogs[name]; }
});
```

Now if you write

```
my.dogname = 'fido'
```

The setter will be called and you will have the dog set in `my.dog`

Since it is a built-in ES feature, it is faster and lower-level than having to rely on any king of listener/watcher/closure.

For instance if setting `$scope.first` is supposed to have side-effects, such as updating `$scope.last`, the setter approach is faster:

```
Object.defineProperty($scope, "$first", {
  set: function (index) { this.$last = this.$first + length } // for instance
});
```

Comment: I'm curious, why do you think a setter would be faster in the way you described? There are no watchers/listeners/closures(? - also "built-in", btw) in that [function of `ng-repeat`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.14/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L288) - it is a simple assignment to a property of the `scope` object. Specifically, the example you showed, the instruction `$last = N` would have to be done either in the setter for `$first` or outside. Why is one faster than the other?

Comment: What I understand from the source you pointed out is that this whole function `updateScope` is precisely triggering a bunch of side effects after the value assignment, and they'd suggest using a setter that would take care of that, instead of calling the function. I cannot prove it's faster but I'm pretty sure these guys know what they're talking about and may have benchmarked it.

Comment: So does that mean that each of these are setting off a watch (I haven't spent too much time in the codebase)? If I have a super long and deep collection being watched with this provide a noticeable difference considering that it only provides 1%. The digest cycle currently takes about a second and includes about 1600 watches

Comment: I wouldn't worry on the impact of this `updateScope` function, it should take a few milliseconds even for thousands of calls. However 1s for *each* digest cycle seems way too much: everytime you'll type text in a `ng-model` input you need to wait 1s between each keypress? You probably have some bottlenecks watchers. I've asked how to detect them but unfortunately no answer yet :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684602/find-slow-watchers-and-bindings-in-an-angular-app

Comment: Mine seems to be in the transcludes. The ng-repeat ends rather quickly but the transcludes take a bit of time each. I came to this by editing angular manually to include console.time.

Comment: Try to remove any watchers/directives from the html you transclude: if it is still slow, unfortunately the problem is that you are generating too much HTML, which is often what takes most of the time. In this case it's often a good idea to have some kind of infinite scrolling where you would compute only a subset of all the items, and create more as the user scrolls.

Comment: We tried that didn't work but we do use pagination I so we have already milked that cow.